# Webpack compilation ignores source change

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack, gulp-watch

I use Webpack + Gulp with build-watch style like explained [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html) (mode 2). 
Occasionally, Webpack ignores the change of JS source. Gulp script is very simple.

```
gulp.task("webpack:build-dev", function(callback) {
   // run webpack
   devCompiler.run(function(err, stats) {
       // Handle error
       callback();
   });
});
```

Complete example is on [Github](https://github.com/burnall/webpack-with-common-libs). After change of index.js, the bundle should reflect the change. It does not happen on first time, then it is working fine. I started from real-life project, and here the pattern was different: 1st, 3rd, 5th etc change was ignored.
Looks as Webpack bug, any other ideas before posting the issue to developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted a bug to Webpack developers (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3137). It is not reproducible in Webpack 2 (currently in beta) and probably will not be fixed for Webpack 1.x.